# d3js basic javascript&css: how to I apply an array of strings (for image urls) to the existing bar chart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

[D3JS]

So what I've tried to do is to make a squared bar chart that's proportional to the size of the data, along with each datum to be assigned with a particular image to be shown.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div.bar {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 75px;   /* Gets overriden by D3-assigned height below */
            margin-right: 2px;
            background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HWtqJNu3blk/UOhy_vj2I3I/AAAAAAAAhdY/U-krgiDfksw/s640/sydney+australia+rubber+duck+1.jpg');
            background-size: 100%;}
    </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5];
            var coverset=['http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HWtqJNu3blk/UOhy_vj2I3I/AAAAAAAAhdY/U-krgiDfksw/s640/sydney+australia+rubber+duck+1.jpg', 
            'http://fora.mtv.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/catsofinstagram.jpg',
'http://www.dogbreedinfo.com/images22/NorthernInuitDogWhiteThunder10Months.jpg',
            ]
            var bar = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("height", function(d) {
                    var barHeight = d * 5;
                    return barHeight + "px";
                })
                .style("width", function(d) {
                    var barWidth = d * 5;
                    return barWidth + "px";
                });
            var img = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
                .data(coverset)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("background-img", function(d){
                    return "url(" + d +")";
                });

        </script>
```

With this code, I get [this](http://s3.postimg.org/9hn136qpf/Screen_Shot_2013_06_10_at_2_49_27_PM.png). 
So half of my code is working, the bar is proportional to the size of each datum, however, 
each bar should have different images as specified in the "coverset", but it only shows a default yellow duck picture, not getting overridden by the D3-assigned image.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong in the image part of the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to accomplish your goal
(revised version of your code sample posted on jsbin).

http://jsbin.com/ocoyal/1/edit

**CSS**

```
div.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;   /* Gets overriden by D3-assigned height below */
    margin-right: 2px;
    background-image: url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HWtqJNu3blk/UOhy_vj2I3I/AAAAAAAAhdY/U-krgiDfksw/s640/sydney+australia+rubber+duck+1.jpg');

    /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

**JavaScript**

```
            var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5];
            var coverset=['http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HWtqJNu3blk/UOhy_vj2I3I/AAAAAAAAhdY/U-krgiDfksw/s640/sydney+australia+rubber+duck+1.jpg', 
            'http://fora.mtv.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/catsofinstagram.jpg',
'http://www.dogbreedinfo.com/images22/NorthernInuitDogWhiteThunder10Months.jpg',
            ]
            var bar = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("height", function(d) {
                    var barHeight = d * 5;
                    return barHeight + "px";
                })
                .style("width", function(d) {
                    var barWidth = d * 5;
                    return barWidth + "px";
                })
               //  "background-image", not "background-img"
               //  using "i" for index 
               .style("background-image", function(d, i){
                    return "url(" + coverset[i] +")";
                });
```